# checking if value exists in a list column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I'm a bit puzzled as to why `%in%` does not work when used to compare a value in a list column. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| A | B | 
| --- | --- | 
| '1' | c('1', '3', '9') | 
| '2' | c('1', '2', '5') | 
| '3' | c('4', '5') | 
| '4' | c('1', '2', '5') | 
| '5' | c('1', '2', '5') |
```

and I want to add column C that has whether A exists in B. When I try the following (let's say the above dataframe is called df)

```
df %>% mutate(C = ifelse(A %in% B, 1, 0))
```

I get this

```
| A | B | C |
 | --- | --- | --- | 
| '1' | c('1', '3', '9') | 0 | 
| '2' | c('1', '2', '5') | 0 | 
| '3' | c('4', '5') | 0 | 
| '4' | c('1', '2', '5') | 0 | 
| '5' | c('1', '2', '5') | 0 |
```

What I want is:

```
| A | B | C |
 | --- | --- | --- | 
| '1' | c('1', '3', '9') | 1 | 
| '2' | c('1', '2', '5') | 1 | 
| '3' | c('4', '5') | 0 | 
| '4' | c('1', '2', '5') | 0 | 
| '5' | c('1', '2', '5') | 1 |
```

Why do I get the result that I get, and how can I get around it?

I also tried `is.element()` instead of `%in%` but the result is the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DO NOT POST YOUR QUESTION OR CODE AS IMAGES. Please edit your question format  it properly

Comment: just don't use dplyr and everything will be good again.

Comment: It does not like tables in markdown, apparently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you use `rowwise()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
tib <- tibble(A = 1:5, 
       B = list(c(1,3,9), c(1,2,5), c(4,5), c(1,2,5), c(1,2,5)))
tib %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(C = as.numeric(A %in% B))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A B             C
#>   <int> <list>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 <dbl [3]>     1
#> 2     2 <dbl [3]>     1
#> 3     3 <dbl [2]>     0
#> 4     4 <dbl [3]>     0
#> 5     5 <dbl [3]>     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(C = +(map2_lgl(A, B, ~ .x %in% .y)))
```